# JSSOR Slider: Text and images not showing on Internet Explorer, including IE 11

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, slider, jssor

Firstly, thank you, to the developer of the jssor slider. I am using it on one of my projects. It's working as it should except on any version of IE. The slider background images show and they fade from one image to the next. But the text on the primary slide is not showing on top of these images. Also, there is a little "banner-like" slide of sponsors below the primary slider which does not show the sponsor images on IE. See the site [here](http://development.infowest.com/whatsup).

If I use IE's inspect element and change from Edge to 10, the text momentarily shows and then the page reloads and the text is gone again.

Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: include relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you specify width in 'rem' manner.

Please specify size of elements in pixel,

```
<div class="hero-slider-container" id="hero-slider-container">

<div class="contain-slides" u="slides">
```

Comment: This fixed it! You know your stuff, jssor! I was even using a px fallback but that wasn't good enough. I eliminated the rems and used only pixels and it's working on IE 11. Thank you!